# How to calculate exp(x) for really big integers in Python?

Tags: python, math, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I'm using a sigmoid function for my artificial neural network. The value that I'm passing to the function ranges from 10,000 to 300,000. I need a high-precision answer because that would serve as the weights of the connection between the nodes in my artificial neural network. I've tried looking in numpy but no luck. Is there a way to compute the `e^(-x)`

Comment: Look at either the `GMPY` library or the `long` number type in python

Comment: By Euler number, do you mean `e~=2.71828` or do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number  ?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, what I meant is e ~ 2.71

Comment: Does it make more sense to scale the inputs if their range causes you problems?

Comment: I googled to see if it could be done.  Just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should...

Comment: I do not know if it's ok to scale the values down. In artificial neural network, I guess every number is important.

Comment: related: [Approximation of e<sup>−x</sup>](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71357/1665)

Answer (score 4):

The regular python math and numpy modules will overflow on exp(300000).

What you need is an arbitrary precision floating point library.

Prereq: `pip install mpmath`

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps=300
print exp(300000)
2.21090954962043147554031964344003334958746533182776533253160702399084245726328190320934903726540800347936047182773804396858994958295396516475277561815722954583856797032504775443385287094864178178111231967140927970972263439977028621274619241097429676587262948251263990280758512853239132411057394977398e+130288
```

see also http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/

Comment: Thanks for this! But when I'm doing the sigmoid function, `exp(-300000) + 1`, it outputs just `1`.

Comment: Well you need over 130000 digits.  `mp.dps` sets precision. Looks like it will do it... but you might want to test it... and those 150k digit objects will need memory.

Comment: What I'm doing is
`mp.dps = 130000` then, 
`print exp(-300000)+1`

It still outputs `1`

Comment: Change `mp.dps=300` to `mp.dps=150000` and you will get more digits, so that 1+exp(-300000) outputs 1. a bunch of zeros, and then the digits from exp(-300000).

Comment: I also get 1 if I use `mp.dps=130000` which is not quite enough.

Comment: Yes. Thanks! But I think it's not feasible since the computation is slow.

Comment: Either speed or memory requirement or lack of benefit will probably kill this idea.

Answer (score 4):

@Paul already gave you the answer for computational question

However - from neural network point of view your problem is indication that you are **doing something wrong**. There is no reasonable use of neural networks, where you have to compute such number. You seem to forget about at least one of:

- Input data scaling/normalization/standarization
- small weights bounds initizlization
- regularization term which keeps weights small when the size of network grows

all these elements are basic and **crucial** parts of working with neural networks. I recommend to have a look at *Neural Networks and Learning Machines* by Haykin.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've adjusted my initial weights from (-0.5,0.5), there are 2304 + 1 bias node for my input layer because I'm training a facial expression recognizer. Each value of the node from the input layer ranges from 0 to 255. Being that said, 1 node at the hidden layer can still have a very large number.

Comment: First, input values should also be scaled, to for example [0,1] (or even better [-1,1]), this way the greatest number of in the hidden node becomes 0.5 * 2304 = 1152, and this bound is achievable only for maximal initial values and completely white image. There are also rules of the thumb in hayking which show what should be the initialization bounds. Also if you are using the sigmoid - you can try to compute tanh instead (it is the same function, but is "directly" computable)

Answer (score 2):

`decimal` module from stdlib allows to compute `exp(-300000)` with desired precision:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 300
>>> decimal.Decimal(-300000).exp()
Decimal('4.52302537736869338168154543856941208987901785730658877589102779454404342316583413710153707357620016787644963947448152347606024065141665176979995260298156742722510150887341893137830615617098803353373668680329179329422367091094657806579661636984526349130940466600671093389647604708034230900336526970689E-130289')
```

I agree with [@lejlot' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22730167/4279): if you need it then there is something wrong with your neural networks.

Comment: I can't find my error. I think I'm doing all in track.

Comment: @Larssen: if you think that the value is not an error then you should figure out how to compute its approximate value with a reasonable (small) precision in the context where it is used (`e**-x` is 0 for large `x`, `1 + e**-x` is `1`, you need to find the expression in your program where `e**-x != 0` makes a difference)